# Need Guidence on Adding User Accounts and Payment System to Website

Tags: html, css, web, e-commerce

I have some business ideas I would like to try in the near future that would involve selling digital products like software or datasets. I know how to create a website as far as the HTML and CSS end, but I don't have experience with making web applications or user account systems. I would also be concerned with liability should someones account get hacked or payment information stolen.

I don't think what I need is anything too fancy. The customer needs to be able to create an account, purchase digital products, and give them access to those files on their account. I would also need the ability to remove, update, or add new files to their account after the fact.

Are there services that handle user accounts, hold files, and handle payments in one service? Maybe I could just create my own user account system and have someone else handle all payments? I could use some guidance here.

Comment: Just use free e-commerce CMS like Opencart or prestashop or some similar. Magento not suggesting it is very very "heavy" system and very very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify or Square if you don't want to do anything. You can also try Opencart, Megento, WooCommerce, Prestashop or Drupal Commerce.

*EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:*
I did mean Square, not "Squarespace". Specifically https://squareup.com

Comment: Do any of these services store files, say when a customer pays for the product they can download it off their account?